# Cross table SQL Query to exclude from results records based on keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Here's a head-scratcher (for me)...

I have two tables A and B.  A contains product descriptions, B contains product codes, quantity, and accounts.  The wrinkle here is that B has a parent, child relationships on product codes.

What I would like to do is put together a result set where I see Account, Product, Description and Qty, where one of the product Qty's = 0, EXCEPT if there's a keyword in the Description in the product (whose Qty I don't care about).

So, here's my query right now:

```
SELECT Bp.Account, Bp.Product, A.Description, Bp.Qty FROM B 
AS Bp JOIN A as Prod  ON (Bp.Product = Prod.Product)  
WHERE EXISTS (Select * from B AS Bc 
              WHERE Bp.Account = Bc.Account
              AND Qty = 0)
```

And this returns a very nice result set of:

```
Account  Product Description Qty
ABC      XYZ     DESC-BLAH   1
ABC      XYY     DESC-DEE    0
ABC      ZXY     DESC-BILP   1
BDE      XAZ     DESC-OOPS   1
BDE      XYY     DESC-DEE    0
BDE      ZXY     DESC-BLIP   1
```

So lets say I want to exclude DESC-OOPS, and all products relating to it from my result set.  I would like to see:

```
Account  Product Description Qty
ABC      XYZ     DESC-BLAH   1
ABC      XYY     DESC-DEE    0
ABC      ZXY     DESC-BILP   1
```

Is this possible to do in a single query?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How is parent child relationship in `Table B` established? Is it by `Account`?

Comment: The parent child relationship is established by Product.ID, which I omitted to keep things simpler. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could just add to your WHERE criteria:

```
SELECT Bp.Account, Bp.Product, A.Description, Bp.Qty FROM B 
AS Bp JOIN A as Prod  ON (Bp.Product = Prod.Product)  
WHERE EXISTS (Select * from B AS Bc 
              WHERE Bp.Account = Bc.Account
              AND Qty = 0)
  AND Bp.ACCOUNT NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNT FROM Table WHERE Description = 'DESC-OOPS'
```

I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you, but perhaps:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Bp.Account, Bp.Product, A.Description, Bp.Qty 
      FROM B AS Bp 
      JOIN A as Prod  
         ON (Bp.Product = Prod.Product)  
      WHERE EXISTS (Select * from B AS Bc 
                  WHERE Bp.Account = Bc.Account
                  AND Qty = 0)
      )sub
WHERE ACCOUNT NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNT FROM Table WHERE Description = 'DESC-OOPS'
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this, and I got an error message: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.  So I tried to include it within the EXISTS clause, but still no dice.

Comment: Odd that, there's only one expression in the SELECT list of the subquery, `ACCOUNT`

Comment: Okay, got the query you provided working, but what it does now is suppress just the one record, and not all the related parent records.  The clause now reads 'WHERE EXISTS (Select * from B AS Bc WHERE Bp.Account = Bc.Account and Qty = 0) AND EXISTS (Select * from B where B.Description not like '%OOPS%')'

Comment: Yeah the EXISTS isn't helpful since it identifies only one row, you need to limit by the value for ACCOUNT for that description.  Did you try the queries in the answer, or did you put SELECT * in the subquery?

Comment: Getting closer - now I'm getting invalid object name error when doing the cross-table join on the WHERE ACCOUNT NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNT FROM Table WHERE Description = 'DESC-OOPS'.

Comment: You need the JOIN to determine which account(s) have the description? If so you'll have to put the JOIN in that subquery in place of 'Table'

Comment: Got the query working now...But now there are zero results! So the sub-select query is totally independent from the rest of the query?  Right now it reads:  WHERE EXISTS (as solution)  AND B.Account NOT IN (Select B.Account from B JOIN A as Prod on (B.Acccount = Prod.Account) Where Prod.Description not like '%OOPS%')

Comment: Almost, change that last portion from NOT LIKE to LIKE.

Comment: Thank you!!  That's perfect now, results are exactly what I am expecting!